# Elevated button not working as widget of child in body clause

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have an ElevatedButton widget in this stateless widget. The hierarchy of the brackets is ok but it is not recognizing the ElevatedButton widget being a parameter of child

```
class buildProfileView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  Image.network(controller.googleAccount.value?.photoUrl ?? '')
                      .image,
              radius: 100,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            controller.googleAccount.value?.displayName ?? '',
            style: Get.textTheme.headline1,
          ),
          Text(controller.googleAccount.value?.email ?? '',
              style: Get.textTheme.bodyText1),
          //),
        ],
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Continue to Main Menu'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies on code-strucure

```dart
     //),
        ],
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
```

where `ElevatedButton` is out of the column scope.
It will be

```dart
  body: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage:
                Image.network(controller.googleAccount.value?.photoUrl ?? '')
                    .image,
            radius: 100,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          controller.googleAccount.value?.displayName ?? '',
          style: Get.textTheme.headline1,
        ),
        Text(controller.googleAccount.value?.email ?? '',
            style: Get.textTheme.bodyText1),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Continue to Main Menu'),
        ),
      ]),
```

More about [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)  widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can't assign both child and children property to a Column. Column takes children so move ElevatedButton to children block inside [](square brackets).